# How do I finish my proof that the sequence converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a sequence $x_n$ with the following criterion $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: |x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}|\leq 0.99|x_{n+1}-x_{n}|$$
and I should prove that $x_n$ converges.

Now I know that whenever a sequence is Cauchy it converges and looking at the criterion, it seems to me that this sequence must be a Cauchy sequence. I just do not know how to prove this formally. I know that if I choose an $N$ big enough, then at one point $|x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}|$ will be smaller than any $\epsilon>0$. Any hints on how to finish this proof? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

prove that

$\forall\; n,p \geq0$

$|x_{n+p}-x_n|\leq V_n$  with
 $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}V_n=0$$

using triangular inequality and geometric sum.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $$|x_{k+1}-x_k|\leq 0.99 |x_k-x_{k-1}|\leq 0.99^2 |x_{k-1}-x_{k-2}|\leq\dots\leq (0.99)^k|x_1-x_0|.$$
$$|x_n-x_m|=|\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}(x_{k+1}-x_k)|\leq \sum_{k=m}^{n-1}|x_{k+1}-x_k|\leq \sum_{k=m}^{n-1}(0.99)^k|x_1-x_0|,$$
$$|x_n-x_m|\leq|x_1-x_0|\frac{(0.99)^m-(0.99)^n}{1-0.99}.$$
Since $0.99<1$, we have that sequence $\{(0.99)^k\}_{k\geq 1}$ converges and therefore is Cauchy's. Because of that, expression on the right side is less than $\varepsilon$ for sufficiently large $m,n$. Therefore, $x_n$ is Cauchy's.